# Как освободить динамическую память многомерного массива

Tags: c++, указатели, динамические-массивы

Не могу правильно освободит память, помогите.

```
//создаем многомерный массив указателей, каждый их который будет хранить информацию об одном человеке
int person_num = 1;
char ***full_info = new char**[person_num];
for (int i = 0; i < person_num; i++){
    full_info[i] = new char *[5];
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        full_info[i][j] = new char[10]; 
    }
}

full_info[0][0] = "Sidorow"; full_info[0][1] = "Ivan"; full_info[0][2] = "24"; full_info[0][3] = "1987"; full_info[0][4] = "Filatova 20";


person_num++;
//чтобы добавить человека увеличиваем размер массива
//создать новый массив указателей

char ***temp_full_info = new char**[person_num];
for (int i = 0; i < person_num; i++){
    temp_full_info[i] = new char *[5];
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        temp_full_info[i][j] = new char[10]; 
    }
}
//скопировать старый массив указателей в новый
for (int i = 0; i < person_num - 1; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < num_of_colls; j++){
        temp_full_info[i][j] = full_info[i][j];
    }
    temp_full_info[i] = full_info[i];
}

//освобождение памяти
for (int i = 0; i < person_num - 1; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < num_of_colls; j++){
        delete full_info[i][j];
    }
    delete[] full_info[i];
}
delete[] full_info;
```

Comment: В C++ многомерный массив строк — это `vector<vector<string>>`, а не `char***`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этих циклах

```
char ***full_info = new char**[person_num];
for (int i = 0; i < person_num; i++){
    full_info[i] = new char *[5];
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        full_info[i][j] = new char[10]; 
    }
}
```

Вы динамически выделяли массивы на трех уровнях:

```
char ***full_info = new char**[person_num];
full_info[i] = new char *[5];
full_info[i][j] = new char[10];
```

Следовательно на каждом из этих уровней вам надо освободить выделенную память.

Далее у вас в программе имеется предложение

```
full_info[0][0] = "Sidorow"; full_info[0][1] = "Ivan"; full_info[0][2] = "24"; full_info[0][3] = "1987"; full_info[0][4] = "Filatova 20";
```

Строковые литералы имеют статическую длительность памяти. То есть они распределяются компилятором на этапе компиляции в статической области памяти..

Итак в вышеуказанных циклах вы выделили память

```
full_info[i][j] = new char[10];
```

Значит указатели `full_info[i][j]` указывают на первые байты выделенных символьных массивов `char[10]`. Однако вы затем переписываете значения этих указателей адресами строковых литералов как, например, `full_info[0][0] = "Sidorow";`, и, тем самым, теряете адреса выделенных символьных массивов в вышеприведенном цикле. В результате у вас имеет место утечка памяти. Вы уже не сможете корректно освободить всю выделенную память, так как адреса выделенных символьных массивов у вас утеряны.

Правильно было бы копировать строковые литералы в выделенные массивы как, например,

```
std::strcpy( full_info[0][0], "Sidorow" );
```

Однако вы недостаточного размера выделили символьные массивы и, к примеру, данный строковый литерал `"Filatova 20"`, который имеет тип `const char[12]` не поместится в массиве типа `char[10]`.

Имейте в виду, что и в этих циклах

```
//скопировать старый массив указателей в новый
for (int i = 0; i < person_num - 1; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < num_of_colls; j++){
        temp_full_info[i][j] = full_info[i][j];
    }
    temp_full_info[i] = full_info[i];
}
```

вы также копируете сами указатели вместо того, чтобы копировать содержимое символьных массивов "нижнего" уровня. В результате у вас опять-таки имеет место утечка памяти.

Что касается освобождения памяти, то память, выделенная в вышеуказанных циклах, освобождается в обратном порядке.

```
for (int i = 0; i < person_num; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        delete [] full_info[i][j]; 
    }
    delete [] full_info[i];
}
delete [] full_info;
```

Если у вас значения количества элементов массивов, соответственно равные значениям 5 и 10 (или несколько большее значение), постоянны, то вы могли бы поступить проще. Например

```
char ( *full_info )[5][10] = new char[person_num][5][10];
```

Тогда удалить выделенную память будет очень просто

```
delete [] full_info;
```

Вместо вручную выделения и освобождения памяти вы моглм бы использовать стандартные классы `std::vector` и `std::string`.

Например,

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> full_info( person_num, std::vector<std::string>( 5 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
full_info[i][j] = new char[10];
```

Тут вы выделили память... и тут же

```
full_info[0][0] = "Sidorow";
```

навсегда ее потеряли. У вас больше нет указателя на выделенную память! У вас указатель на статическую строку...

Для копирования строк используйте `strcpy` - и у вас все получится. Вы копируете не содержимое строк, а указатели, и в этом вся ваша ошибка. А потом пытаетесь удалять память, которую *никто не выделял*...